# What is the gossip protocol for?

Tags: validator

I understand that through Proof of History (PoH), there is no need to sync the validators among each other.

However, there is also a gossip protocol on Solana, that validators use to communicate with each other.

What information is sent/received via gossip?

What is the purpose of gossip?

Is it optional, i.e. would the chain still work (maybe just slower, less reliable, etc.) when there is no gossip?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ostensibly to maintain a view of the current status of each node in the cluster.  Primarily node discovery and contact information (service port mappings).  It's also used for various other [status information](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/8015aedfdd27a18357d9759c2ff3cad639a3d649/gossip/src/crds_value.rs#L83-L95) as well as a slow secondary path for votes